# How do I determine the highest and lowest integer in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to determine the highest number and the lowest number out of whatever numbers the user inputs. We're supposed to display those after the user enters 99. Everything I found is using arrays, and we've not yet learned those. Please help!

```
        string input;
        int input2;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        input2 = Convert.ToInt32(input);


        while (input2 != 99)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            input2 = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        }
```

Comment: Ignoring that you know C#, how would you implement the algorithm? Try to describe it in English. And then try to rewrite that using what you know of C#.

Comment: Are you able to write program for finding highest(or lowest) number from an array ? First write a program for finding highest/lowest only, and then combine both

Comment: As an aside you might want to use int.TryParse inplace of Convert.ToInt32 to avoid an exception when user enters "Fish!".

Comment: You say you haven't learned arrays, but you don't say what you *have* learned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of imperative programming is to give a sequence of statements (an algorithm) that mutate state (a set of variables) until it contains the desired result.

For example, your program changes the contents of the variables `input` and `input2` until `input2` contains the value `99`.

To find the highest and lowest integer, define two variables, `highest` and `lowest`. Change their contents in the `while` loop such that, after each iteration, they contain the highest and lowest integer respectively, taking the current input value into account.

Comment: I made the highest and lowest, and set them to equal zero in the first line of code, but I don't understand how I would go about changing the contents of highest and lowest to the integer. I mean, I know how to change it, but I don't know how to make it 'know' that the value is lower or higher than the previous input.

Comment: @JoshClary, just think about it for a second. How do you know that the number 6 is higher then the number 2? How do you compare them together?

Comment: Alright, I think I know what to do now. I created 'highest' and 'lowest' and set them to 0, and put a line of code in that says
`if (input2 > highest)

                    highest = input2;

                if (input2 < lowest)

                    lowest = input2;`

Comment: The only problem now is that the lowest will never be lower than 0. So I'm kind of stuck on what to do next.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. By setting them to 99 initially, the lowest values and highest values can be set since I'm entering at least one value greater and one less than 99. Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the integers in a list you can use the linq extension methods .Min() to return lowest integer and .Max() to return highest integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need some variable to record the max and min (what values should you initialize these to?).  On each user input/loop iteration you should compare user input to the current values of these variables and update them if necessary (there are several ways to do that - some more verbose than others).  You need to decide (check spec) how to handle 99 eg does that count as min or max?

Answer (score -3):

```
int min = int.Max;
int max = int.Min;

// ...

while (input2 != 99) {
    // ...
    min = Math.Min(min, input2);
    max = Math.Max(max, input2);
}

// At this point, min and max contain the desired result.
```

There are couple of edge cases here, for example what if user enters 99 right away or she enters only `int.Max` for `min` (or `int.Min` for `max`), but I'll let you handle that...

Comment: @Ricibob This is the most concise format I could think of for expressing the basic idea. You'll notice I did not produce the full code and I mentioned he should think about edge cases, so this is hardly something he can just copy-paste without trying to understand it.